# Question regarding n consecutive positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for any  positive integers $m$  and $n$, there exist a set of n consecutive positive  integers each of which is divisible by a number of the form $a^m$ where a is some integer in $\mathbb N$

This question is from the book Challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics, Chapter 2 (last problem)

I assume the authors meant $a > 1$ as $a = 1$ would be a trivial solution

Answer (score 1):

Pick  pairwise relatively prime numbers $a_1,\ldots ,a_n$ (for example the first $n$ primes). Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists a solution to the congruences $x\equiv -k\pmod{a_k^m}$

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate  consequence of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) Let $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ be $n$ distinct primes. Then since the $p_i^m$ are pairwise relatively prime, the system of congruences
$$x\equiv -i \pmod{p_i^m},\quad 1\le i\le n,$$ 
 has a solution $x$. Indeed it has infinitely many solutions, for if $x$ is any solution, then $x+k(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^m$ is a solution.

But for any solution $x$, the number $p_i^m$ divides $x+i$, which is precisely what we want.